# Show $\frac{P^2(A)}{P(A+1)}$ is Bounded when $P$ is Gaussian Measure

Tags: probability, probability-theory, measure-theory, probability-distributions

Suppose that $P$ is a standard Gaussian measure. Can we show that 
$$\sup_{\cal A} \left( \frac{P^2(\cal A)}{P(\cal A + 1 )}  \right) $$
is bounded?

Here $\cal A + 1 $ means that we perturb each element of $\cal A$ by 1.

Also, can we show that
$$\sup_{\cal A} \left( \frac{P(\cal A)}{P(\cal A + 1 )}  \right) $$
is bounded?

I believe that the latter is unbounded but the former should be bounded. Although, I do not know a formal way of approaching either problem.

Answer (score 3):

Showing the latter is unbounded is easy. Take an interval like $[n,n+\epsilon]$ for large n. When you shift it by a constant $\delta$, the integrand, which is roughly $e^{-x^2}$, will decrease by a factor of roughly $e^{-n\delta}$. So the ratio grow like $e^{n\delta}$ so unbounded.

For the former, try reducing the problem to intervals first and check if it is bounded or not on them.

Showing bounded is complicated by the fact you need to analyse all type of sets. But this should reduce to intervals as the pdf is monotone for positive $x$.

I strongly suspect you should look at the sup when $P(A)$ is fixed. I suspect that for fixed $P(A)$, the quantity of interest is maximized for all the weight in the right tail.

Comment: I have been trying to reduce from all sets $\cal A$ to intervals, yet I am unable to see that connection immediately.